# IDisposable objects as ref param to method

Tags: c#

I was doing a refactoring of class and thought of moving 100 lines in a separate method. Like this:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

 class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem))
            {
                doc.Open();
                AddContent(ref doc, ref wri);
                doc.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\testpdf.pdf", mem.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AddContent(ref Document doc, ref PdfWriter writer)
    {
        var header = new Paragraph("My Document") { Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
        var paragraph = new Paragraph("Testing the iText pdf.");
        var phrase = new Phrase("This is a phrase but testing some formatting also. \nNew line here.");
        var chunk = new Chunk("This is a chunk.");
        doc.Add(header);
        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Add(phrase);
        doc.Add(chunk);

    }
}
```

At calling method of Compiler throws exception : ***Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target*** for doc and mem.

**Edit:** here only i adding content in `pdf` document in another method. so i need to pass same doc object, right ? so why can't i use `ref` or out `param`.

Technically `using` defies the purpose of `ref` param here.

Tried to look on MSDN:

```
A ReadOnly property has been found in a context that assigns a value to it. 
Only writable variables, properties, and array elements can have values assigned
to them during execution.
```

How the objects become read only at calling of Method? Within the scope object is alive and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Nope, that's not a short but complete program. By "short but complete program" I mean "something I can copy and paste into a new text file, compile and run with no changes".

Comment: Try copying and pasting that into a new text file and compiling it. What is the `Document` class? What is the `PdfWriter` class? `Paragraph`? `Chunk`? `Phrase`? I strongly suspect they are irrelevant to the question, and that you just need *some* `IDisposable` implementation - so use one within the BCL, and add an appropriate `using` directive.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry Forget to mention itextSharp here. `pdfwriter ,paragraph ,chunk ...` defined in itextsharp library.

Comment: You've missed my point - you're asking about a language error, which has nothing to do with iTextSharp. If I want to reproduce this, it's a *lot* easier for me to do so without downloading iTextSharp - so you should include code which doesn't need it. I suspect you've misunderstood what `ref` does, mind you. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @JonSkeet , Agrees with you on this. itextsharp not required here at all. but this is just how i explaining the object scope. where same object is required for contiguous operations.

Comment: So use a different type - one which allows a genuine short but complete program to be presented. It's important to put effort into asking a question without anything irrelevant in it. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (and as I said, read my article about parameter passing - I think this question is a symptom of a bigger misunderstanding)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you declare `doc` and `mem` using the `using` keyword. Citing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

Hence you get the error about the read-only variable.

---

If you still want to pass parameters by reference, you can use `try ... finally` block instead of `using`. As pointed out by Jon Skeet, this code is similar to how `using` is expanded but with a `using` statement, it's always the original object which is disposed. In the code below, if `AddContent` changes the value of `doc`, it will be that later value which is used in the `Dispose` call.

```
var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);
try
{
     var mem = new MemoryStream();
     try
     {
         PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
         doc.Open();
         AddContent(ref doc,ref wri );
         doc.Close();
     }
     finally
     {
         if (mem != null)
             ((IDisposable)mem).Dispose();
     }
 }
 finally
 {
     if (doc != null)
         ((IDisposable)doc).Dispose();
 }
 return output.ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for helping and explaining it to me, but this doesn't solves my problem.

Comment: This *isn't* the same code as with `using` - because with a `using` statement, it's always the *original* object which is disposed. In your "equivalent" code, if `AddContent` changes the value of `doc`, it will be that later value which is used in the `Dispose` call.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, I'll modify the answer to make it clear. Done.

Answer (score 6):

the `mem` variable is readonly, because of the `using` keyword. How should the compiler know otherwise what he has to dispose when leaving the using-scope when you override it's reference to the variable.

But why do you have to use the `ref` keyword anyway? In my opinion you do not need a ref.

Comment: may be ref wont require here . take a requirement of generating `pdf `document, you need to retain the same document object. this is what i did.

Comment: In theory, the contract around `using` could just be "disposes whatever's in the variable at the end of the block", so if you switch it out it'll just dispose whatever you switch it for... but it's not :) +1 for "you do not need a ref".

Comment: @joshua: You *really* need to make sure you understand what `ref` does. It's important in order to use C# properly. See the link included in the question comments. I'm pretty sure that removing `ref` is the *best* solution here.